# pylab matplotlib "show" waits until window closes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to have the matplotlib "show" command return to the command line
while displaying the plot.  Most other plot packages, like R, do this.
But pylab hangs until the plot window closes.  For example:

```
import pylab
x = pylab.arange( 0, 10, 0.1)
y = pylab.sin(x)
pylab.plot(x,y, 'ro-')
pylab.show()   #  Python hangs here until the plot window is closed
```

I'd like to be able to view the plot while doing command line queries.
I'm running Debian squeeze with python 2.6.6.
My ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc contains

```
backend      : GTKAgg
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try using [IPython](http://ipython.org/)

Comment: you mean `ipython -pylab` to get the multithreading.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add `pylab.ion()` ([interactive mode](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ion)) before the `pylab.show()` call. That will make the UI run in a separate thread and the call to `show` will return immediately.

Comment: Thank you.  Works well.  With `ion()`, the `show()` command is no longer needed.

Comment: It indeed immediately returns, but why the figure hangs there showing "Not Responding"

Answer (score 5):

You need to run it as

```
$ ipython --pylab
```

and run your code as

```
In [8]: x = arange(0,10,.1)

In [9]: y = sin(x)

In [10]: plot(x,y,'ro-')

Out[10]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x2f2fd50>]

In [11]:
```

This gives you the prompt for cases where you would want to modify other parts or plot more.